# Webpack suddenly broke

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

A week ago it was working fine. Now, without any changes (same PC and exactly same files - no diff against repo), after `npm install` it is no longer working and crashing with following error:

```
user@machine:~/workspace/work/project$ npm run build

> project@0.0.1 build /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project
> rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail

 10% building modules 3/12 modules 9 active ...h-fe/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.jsModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'css' in '/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project'
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:232:38
    at onDoneResolving (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:40:20)
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:159:21
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3853:9
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:484:16
    at iteratorCallback (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1082:13)
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:988:16
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3850:13
    at apply (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:41:25)
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:76:12
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:484:16
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1161:9
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:484:16
    at iteratorCallback (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1082:13)
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:988:16
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1158:13
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:216:19
    at onResolved (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:70:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at afterInnerCallback (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:138:10)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at Resolver.applyPluginsAsyncSeriesBailResult1 (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:108:46)
    at innerCallback (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:125:19)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:210:15
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:39:4
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at afterInnerCallback (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:138:10)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at Resolver.applyPluginsAsyncSeriesBailResult1 (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:108:46)
resolve 'css' in '/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/package.json (relative path: .)
  after using description file: /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/package.json (relative path: .)
    resolve as module
      /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /some_outer_path/some_path/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /some_outer_path/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /mnt/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules
        using description file: /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
        after using description file: /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/css)
            as directory
              /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/css doesn't exist
            no extension
              /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/css doesn't exist
            .js
              /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/css.js doesn't exist
            .json
              /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/css.json doesn't exist

/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:197
                        _this.errors.push(err);
        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of null
    at errorAndCallback (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:197:9)
    at errorOrWarningAndCallback (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:228:13)
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:232:12
    at onDoneResolving (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:40:20)
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:159:21
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3853:9
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:484:16
    at iteratorCallback (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1082:13)
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:988:16
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3850:13
    at apply (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:41:25)
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:76:12
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:484:16
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1161:9
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:484:16
    at iteratorCallback (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1082:13)
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:988:16
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1158:13
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:216:19
    at onResolved (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:70:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at afterInnerCallback (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:138:10)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at Resolver.applyPluginsAsyncSeriesBailResult1 (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:108:46)
    at innerCallback (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:125:19)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:210:15
    at /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:39:4
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at afterInnerCallback (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:138:10)

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-45-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.8.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! project@0.0.1 build: `rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the project@0.0.1 build script 'rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the project package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs project
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls project
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/project/npm-debug.log
```

webpack.config.js (mostly from this seed - https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack/):

```
// Helper: root() is defined at the bottom
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

// Webpack Plugins
var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');
var ForkCheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').ForkCheckerPlugin;

/**
 * Env
 * Get npm lifecycle event to identify the environment
 */
var ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var isTestWatch = ENV === 'test-watch';
var isTest = ENV === 'test' || isTestWatch;
var isProd = ENV === 'build';

module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig() {
  /**
   * Config
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html
   * This is the object where all configuration gets set
   */
  var config = {};

  /**
   * Devtool
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
   * Type of sourcemap to use per build type
   */
  if (isProd) {
    config.devtool = 'source-map';
  }
  else if (isTest) {
    config.devtool = 'inline-source-map';
  }
  else {
    config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
  }

  /**
   * Entry
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
   */
  config.entry = isTest ? {} : {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts' // our angular app
  };

  /**
   * Output
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output
   */
  config.output = isTest ? {} : {
    path: root('dist'),
    publicPath: isProd ? '/' : 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: isProd ? 'js/[name].[hash].js' : 'js/[name].js',
    chunkFilename: isProd ? '[id].[hash].chunk.js' : '[id].chunk.js'
  };

  /**
   * Resolve
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
   */
  config.resolve = {
    // only discover files that have those extensions
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html'],
  };

  var atlOptions = '';
  if (isTest && !isTestWatch) {
    // awesome-typescript-loader needs to output inlineSourceMap for code coverage to work with source maps.
    atlOptions = 'inlineSourceMap=true&sourceMap=false';
  }

  /**
   * Loaders
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders
   * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-loaders.html
   * This handles most of the magic responsible for converting modules
   */
  config.module = {
    rules: [
      // Support for .ts files.
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader?' + atlOptions, 'angular2-template-loader', '@angularclass/hmr-loader'],
        exclude: [isTest ? /\.(e2e)\.ts$/ : /\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/]
      },

      // copy those assets to output
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]?'
      },

      // Support for *.json files.
      {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json'},

      // Support for CSS as raw text
      // use 'null' loader in test mode (https://github.com/webpack/null-loader)
      // all css in src/style will be bundled in an external css file
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: root('src', 'app'),
        loader: isTest ? 'null' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
          loader: ['css', 'postcss']
        })
      },
      // all css required in src/app files will be merged in js files
      {test: /\.css$/, include: root('src', 'app'), loader: 'raw!postcss'},

      // support for .scss files
      // use 'null' loader in test mode (https://github.com/webpack/null-loader)
      // all css in src/style will be bundled in an external css file
      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
        exclude: root('src', 'app'),
        loader: isTest ? 'null' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
          loader: ['css', 'postcss', 'sass']
        })
      },
      // all css required in src/app files will be merged in js files
      {test: /\.(scss|sass)$/, exclude: root('src', 'style'), loader: 'raw!postcss!sass'},

      // support for .html as raw text
      // todo: change the loader to something that adds a hash to images
      {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw', exclude: root('src', 'public')}
    ]
  };

  if (isTest && !isTestWatch) {
    // instrument only testing sources with Istanbul, covers ts files
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.ts$/,
      enforce: 'post',
      include: path.resolve('src'),
      loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
      exclude: [/\.spec\.ts$/, /\.e2e\.ts$/, /node_modules/]
    });
  }

  // if (!isTest || !isTestWatch) {
  //   // tslint support
  //   config.module.rules.push({
  //     test: /\.ts$/,
  //     enforce: 'pre',
  //     loader: 'tslint'
  //   });
  // }

  /**
   * Plugins
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
   * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html
   */
  config.plugins = [
    // Define env variables to help with builds
    // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      // Environment helpers
      'process.env': {
        ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    }),

    // Workaround needed for angular 2 angular/angular#11580
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
      root('./src') // location of your src
    ),

    // Tslint configuration for webpack 2
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        /**
         * Apply the tslint loader as pre/postLoader
         * Reference: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
         */
        tslint: {
          emitErrors: false,
          failOnHint: false
        },
        /**
         * Sass
         * Reference: https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader
         * Transforms .scss files to .css
         */
        sassLoader: {
          //includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss")]
        },
        /**
         * PostCSS
         * Reference: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer-core
         * Add vendor prefixes to your css
         */
        postcss: [
          autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 version']
          })
        ]
      }
    })

    // new webpack.ProvidePlugin({Quill: 'Quill'})
  ];

  if (!isTest && !isProd) {
    config.plugins.push(new DashboardPlugin());
  }

  if (!isTest && !isTestWatch) {
    config.plugins.push(
      new ForkCheckerPlugin(),

      // Generate common chunks if necessary
      // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html
      // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['vendor', 'polyfills']
      }),

      // Inject script and link tags into html files
      // Reference: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/public/index.html',
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
      }),

      // Extract css files
      // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin
      // Disabled when in test mode or not in build mode
      new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: 'css/[name].[hash].css', disable: !isProd})
    );
  }

  // Add build specific plugins
  if (isProd) {
    config.plugins.push(
      // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#noerrorsplugin
      // Only emit files when there are no errors
      new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),

      // // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#dedupeplugin
      // // Dedupe modules in the output
      // new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),

      // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin
      // Minify all javascript, switch loaders to minimizing mode
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({sourceMap: true, mangle: {keep_fnames: true}}),

      // Copy assets from the public folder
      // Reference: https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
        from: root('src/public')
      }])
    );
  }

  /**
   * Dev server configuration
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devserver
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html
   */
  config.devServer = {
    contentBase: './src/public',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    quiet: true,
    stats: 'minimal' // none (or false), errors-only, minimal, normal (or true) and verbose
  };

  return config;
}();

// Helper functions
function root(args) {
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return path.join.apply(path, [__dirname].concat(args));
}
```

Any idea what could broke and why? How to fix it?

Edit1: webpack version is <s>2.1.0-beta.25</s> 2.1.0-beta.26 (Edit3)

Edit2: The seed is not working as well (just to be crystal clear - it was working fine a week ago too). It is crashing with this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Can't add property fileName, object is not extensible
    at Object.Linter (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/angular2-webpack-official/node_modules/tslint/lib/tslint.js:12:23)

ERROR in ./src/vendor.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Can't add property fileName, object is not extensible
    at Object.Linter (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/angular2-webpack-official/node_modules/tslint/lib/tslint.js:12:23)

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Can't add property fileName, object is not extensible
    at Object.Linter (/some_outer_path/some_path/workspace/work/angular2-webpack-official/node_modules/tslint/lib/tslint.js:12:23)
```

It is a same error I get if I allow ts-lint in my project. But I think ts-lint is just crashing on wrong input (something else in a chain broke it earlier).

I am pretty sure I did not change node or npm. I really don't have a clue. Here are project dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.1.0",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^2.0.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^1.2.5",
    "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^3.2.1",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.15.0",
    "angular2-recaptcha": "^0.3.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "ng2-translate": "^3.1.3",
    "primeng": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "quill": "^1.1.3",
    "ramda": "^0.22.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "tsmonad": "^0.6.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.29",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/protractor": "^1.5.16",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.44.26",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.26",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.8.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.3",
    "karma": "1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.3",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.4",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "protractor": "^3.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.6.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "tslint": "^3.4.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.4.4",
    "typescript": "2.0.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.25",
    "webpack-dashboard": "^0.1.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.9"
  }
```

Comment: Looks like it cannot load a dependency. You say files were not changed but you run npm install which definitely changes the files. It complains about quill.js, maybe you can try to set the version for this library explicitly for two weeks ago and this would solve the problem

Comment: By "change files" I meant project source files and configurations. I'll try to look at the quill, but I am don't think it is the problem, because I also tried the seed without modifications and it is not working as well :(. I'll update the question shortly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you sure you're not running beta26? If you ran npm install in the last 8 hours you could have got the new release with breaking changes how loaders are resolved

Run
`./node_modules/.bin/webpack -v`

With beta26 or higher you need to append "-loader" to every loader name or add "-loader" the  `resolveLoader.moduleExtions`

In youre case i would change file to file-loader
`loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]?`

You can also opt-in the old way by specifying moduleExtensions explicitly on the resolveLoader object

```
resolveLoader: {
    moduleExtensions: ['-loader']
}
```

I just had this similar problem myself

[Webpack v2.1.0-beta.26 release notes](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v2.1.0-beta.26)

> Breaking Changes:
>
> -loader is no longer automatically added when resolving loaders
>
> This was removed because it often lead to problems.
>
> You can still opt-in to the old behavior with the resolveLoader.moduleExtensions configuration option.

Comment: I thought this "-loader" thing was already in. It was in the documentation before beta26 at least.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I have 26 not 25. I'll take a look at those `loader`s.

Comment: After adding suffixes to a bunch of loaders (css, raw, file, null and some others) it seems to be working as before :). Thank you very much.

Comment: I've added an  example to opt-in the old way so you don't have specify it explicitly on every loader