# Webpack Compiles With Errors After Computer Restart

Tags: node.js, express, angular, webpack

*** Updated with new errors,

After running

```
 webpack --display-error-details
```

I get a more detailed error. please notice it appears to be looking for node_modules going backwards in directories out of my project.

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'html' in
>   '/Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devops/htdocs/riverwalk' BREAKING CHANGE:
>   It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' prefix when using
>   loaders.
>                    You need to specify 'html-loader' instead of 'html'. resolve 'html' in '/Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devops/htdocs/riverwalk'
>   Parsed request is a module   using description file:
>   /Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devops/htdocs/riverwalk/package.json
>   (relative path: .)   after using description file:
>   /Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devops/htdocs/riverwalk/package.json
>   (relative path: .)
>       resolve as module
>         /Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devops/htdocs/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         /Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devops/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         /Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         /Users/wuno/Dropbox/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         /Users/wuno/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         /Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory

I have been working on an Angular 2 express app for a few months and have dealt with the common `webpack` breaking for no reason. Normally I delete the node_modules folder and run `npm install` which fixes any issues. This time without changing anything `webpack` will not compile.

I pushed my project to git. Everything was working great. I shut my computer down to go to a meeting. Once I opened everything back up and ran `webpack` I get an error which states Can't resolve html in... This error appears for every component in my project. One for each separate view. This is a exact error for the first page it throws on,

```
ERROR in ./assets/app/layouts/public.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'html' in '/Users/wuno/Dropbox/google/devops/htdocs/mypp'
 @ ./assets/app/layouts/public.component.ts 25:18-52
 @ ./assets/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./assets/app/main.ts
```

I am at a loss for how to proceed here. I even cloned my git repo at my last working push and it throws the same errors when running webpack.

This is my webpack config file,

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common.js');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

    output: {
        path: './public/js/app',
        publicPath: "/js/app/",
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    }
});
```

Angular components are at

```
/assets/app/
```

`index.html` is at,

`/public/index.htm`l

This is my app.js in the root directory,

```
var express = require('express');
var models = require('./models/');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var appRoutes = require('./routes/index');
// api controllers
var authors = require('./controllers/authors');
var books = require('./controllers/books');
var books = require('./controllers/address');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    next();
});

// Route app to index.html and hand off to angular2
app.use('/', appRoutes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    return res.render('index');
});

models.sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(function () {
    console.log('Connection successful');
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error creating connection:", error);
  });

module.exports = app;
```

Any help would be appreciated. At the very least how can I debug this further?

Comment: I've had this if I've blown away my source maps and forgotten to regenerate them.

Comment: @silentsod thanks man. What do you mean by source maps?

Comment: Please see the beginning of my question I updated it with more information.

Comment: It sort of states what the issue is, but you don't include anything that's referred to. Unrelated, but keeping node_modules dirs on Dropbox seems like an awful idea.

Comment: I keep all of my projects in drop box. I don't see why that is a bad idea. It makes life super easy. Especially when moving from machine to machine. Thanks for your help though man. Would you please tell me what you see. I must be missing something.

Comment: I get it is saying to use html-loader. Which is installed in my package.json. But riverwalk is the project folder. Not a file. So I have no clue where it is saying that I am not using loader correctly.

Comment: It's looking for `node_modules` in every folder under `/` and didn't find one.

Comment: Yes but node modules exist.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584326/webpack-suddenly-broke/40584774#40584774

Would be the answer to the -loader is required bit. Especially if you just installed webpack without specifying an exact version.